# Data Structures Assignment

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, clion

I have an assignment in my CS class(data structures) and i keep getting the error above.
Basically i need to write code in c++ where the user gives a number of linked lists, then the program gets a random linked list size(from 100-200) as well as a random element(from 0 to 50) to add to the linked list itself. The goal is to create a final array named output, where you have the elements of the linked lists that appear on at least or more than half of the lists given(you must count each element once per list).
I am getting an error(Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
Why am i getting this error?
Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int data;
    node*next;
};
class linkedlistCreation{
private:node*head,*tail;
public:linkedlistCreation()
    {
        head=NULL;
        tail=NULL;
    }
    void addnode(int random){
        node*tmp=new node;
        tmp->data=random;
        tmp->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL){
            head=tmp;
            tail=tmp;
        }else{
            tail->next=tmp;
            tail=tail->next;
        }

    }

};


int main() {
    linkedlistCreation a;
    int k;
    int i;
    int j;
    int listsize;
    int element;
    default_random_engine generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> list_size_distribution(100, 200);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> data_element_distribution(0, 50);
    auto random_list_size = bind(list_size_distribution, generator);
    auto random_element = bind(data_element_distribution, generator);
    cout << "Give number of lists:" ;
    cin >> k;
    int NumbersList[50]={0};
    int CheckingList[50]={0};
    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        listsize=random_list_size();
        CheckingList[50]={0};//Initializing the checking List

        for(j=0;j<=listsize;j++){
            element=random_element();
            cout<<element<<endl;
            a.addnode(element);
            if (CheckingList[element]==0){
                NumbersList[element]=NumbersList[element]+1;
                CheckingList[element]=CheckingList[element]+1;
            }
        }


  

//    for (i=0;i<k;i++){
//        if(NumbersList[i]>=k/2){
//             output[i]=i;
//             cout<<output[i]<<endl;
//
//        }
//
//
//    }
    return 0;






}
```

Comment: a.cpp:49:9: error: 'CheckingList' was not declared in this scope

Comment: The code you show here [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/E91Wq5PKa).  Please [edit] your question to show the real code you are running.

Comment: Style suggestions: keep your loop variables in the loop. The calls to `bind()` are less than ideal. Call the distribution directly, or us a lambda.

Comment: With my understanding of the desired result, this does not require a linked list at all.

Comment: `CheckingList[50]={0};` is likely a bug and it won't do what you want. Maybe you wanted to type `int CheckingList[50]={0};`

Comment: Final comment, with the ranges provided. Every number is incredibly likely to appear in every list.

Comment: Yes i deleted some lines when i pasted it in stackoverflow(int CheckingList[50]={0};)this was one of them.This is not the problem..

Comment: _"Yes i deleted some lines...This is not the problem"_. By deleting those lines, no one else can reproduce your exact problem.  Please [edit] this question to include a [mcve].  Consider the possibility that you are not sure where the problem is.

Comment: okay edited it..The program should run now.

Comment: @sweenish no it doesnt..though this is a data structures assignment so we are required to use them.

Comment: My solution uses data structures. The difference is that I use the data structures that will most effectively solve the problem.

Comment: `CheckingList[50]={0};//Initializing the checking List` is undefined behavior. It attempts to set the 51st item in an array of size 50 to 0. It does not reset the valid elements to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Something worth understanding up front about the assignment is that every number in the range [0, 50] will easily appear in at least half of the lists when the list size is in the range [100, 200]. For the smallest possible list, if I were to manually uniformly distribute numbers, I would simply start at 0 and write every consecutive number. This means that every number will appear once in every list. Make it random, and there's a chance that a number never makes it, but it's low. So the required output seems rather pointless.

If we are to focus solely on the desired output, a linked list is an awful way to go about this. Breaking it down a bit further:

- Generate 'n' sequences of random numbers in the range [0, 50].
- Note what numbers appear in each sequence
- Keep track of how many times a number appears in any sequence
- Output the numbers that appear in at least half of the sequences (every number, basically)

Instead of a linked list, I'm going to use `std::set`. It is ordered, and more importantly, every element is *unique*. Using `std::set` eliminates the need to deal with duplicates.

I then keep count in a `std::map<int, int>` where the key is a number in the range [0, 50], and the key-value is the count of that number appearing in 'n' sequences.

Finally, printing is easy. I just go through map and see if the count qualifies or not.

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> list_size(100, 200);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> element_range(0, 50);

  int num;
  std::cout << "Number: ";
  std::cin >> num;

  std::map<int, int> intCountPerList;
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    int size = list_size(prng);
    std::set<int> s;

    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
      s.insert(element_range(prng));
    }

    for (auto num : s) {
      ++intCountPerList[num];
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Numbers that appeared in at least half of the 'lists': \n";
  int numLength = std::to_string(num).length();
  for (auto count : intCountPerList) {
    if (count.second >= num / 2) {
      std::cout << std::setw(numLength) << count.first << ": " << count.second
                << " times.\n";
    }
  }
}
```

If you are required to use a linked list, the program remains basically unchanged. You just add the extra work of generating a list and then adding the values in the list to the `std::set`. If you don't want to use `std::set`, you'll need to manually keep a count of each number per list. It's just adding needless middle-man work, but it's doable.

Before I go on, I have a mini-rant about the way too many people are learning linked lists in C++. It's wrong. If C++ is your language, use it. Make a class, add iterators, make it a template class. A linked list is a culmination of a lot of principles and practices in C++ like RAII, but it all gets thrown out because we're going to call a globally visible `struct` and a few free funtions a 'data structure.' It's really annoying. Rant over.

My list is doubly linked, the main reason being it's about twice as good :-P. In all seriousness, many operations are much easier to write with a doubly linked list. And managing the extra pointer is a small cost to pay. It also has iterators, which allow for expected traversals. Meaning I can use a range-based for loop with it. This list is not complete, but it's one I keep around, mostly for SO answers.

```cpp
#ifndef MY_LIST_HPP
#define MY_LIST_HPP

#include <algorithm>  // std::swap
#include <cstddef>  // std::size_t

/*
 * Pre-declare template class and friends
 */
template <typename T>
class List;

template <typename T>
void swap(List<T>& lhs, List<T>& rhs);

/*
 * List Class Declaration
 */
template <typename T>
class List {
 public:
  List() = default;
  List(T val);
  List(const List& other);
  List(List&& other);
  ~List();

  void push_front(T val);
  void push_back(T val);

  class iterator;
  iterator begin();
  iterator end();
  // iterator find(T val);

  std::size_t size() const;

  iterator erase(iterator toErase);  // Implement
  void clear();
  bool operator=(List other);
  friend void swap<T>(List& lhs, List& rhs);

 private:
  struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    Node* next = nullptr;

    Node(T val) : data(val) {}
  };

  Node* m_head = nullptr;
  Node* m_tail = nullptr;
  std::size_t m_size = 0;

  // Helper functions
  void make_first_node(T val);
  Node* find_node(T val);
};

/*
 * List Iterator Declaration
 */
template <typename T>
class List<T>::iterator {
 public:
  iterator() = default;
  iterator(List<T>::Node* node);  // minimum
  T& operator*();                 // minimum
  iterator& operator++();         // minimum
  iterator operator++(int);
  iterator& operator--();
  iterator operator--(int);
  bool operator==(const iterator& other);  // minimum
  bool operator!=(const iterator& other);  // minimum
 private:
  Node* m_pos = nullptr;
};

/*
 * List Implementation
 */
template <typename T>
List<T>::List(T val) : m_head(new Node(val)), m_tail(m_head), m_size(1) {}

template <typename T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& other) {
  m_head = new Node((other.m_head)->data);
  m_tail = m_head;
  m_size = 1;

  Node* walker = (other.m_head)->next;
  while (walker) {
    push_back(walker->data);
    ++m_size;
    walker = walker->next;
  }
}

template <typename T>
List<T>::List(List&& other) : List() {
  swap(*this, other);
}

template <typename T>
List<T>::~List() {
  clear();
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::push_front(T val)
{
  if (!m_head) {
    make_first_node(val);
    return;
  }

  Node* tmp = new Node(val);
  tmp->next = m_head;
  m_head->prev = tmp;
  m_head = tmp;
  ++m_size;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::push_back(T val) {
  if (!m_head) {
    make_first_node(val);
    return;
  }

  Node* tmp = new Node(val);
  tmp->prev = m_tail;
  m_tail->next = tmp;
  m_tail = tmp;
  ++m_size;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::begin() {
  return iterator(m_head);
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end() {
  return iterator(nullptr);
}

// template <typename T>
// typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::find(T val) {
//   return iterator(find_node(val));
// }

template <typename T>
std::size_t List<T>::size() const {
  return m_size;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(typename List<T>::iterator toErase)
{
  Node* node = find_node(*toErase);

  if (node->prev) {
    node->prev->next = node->next;
  } else {
    m_head = node->next;
  }

  if (node->next) {
    node->next->prev = node->prev;
  } else {
    m_tail = node->prev;
  }

  Node* toReturn = node->next;
  delete node;

  return toReturn;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::clear() {
  Node* tmp = m_head;
  while (m_head) {
    m_head = m_head->next;
    delete tmp;
    tmp = m_head;
  }
  m_tail = nullptr;
  m_size = 0;
}

template <typename T>
bool List<T>::operator=(List other) {
  swap(*this, other);

  return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::make_first_node(T val) {
  m_head = new Node(val);
  m_tail = m_head;
  m_size = 1;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::Node* List<T>::find_node(T val) {
  if (!m_head) {
    return nullptr;
  }

  Node* walker = m_head;
  while (walker != nullptr && walker->data != val) {
    walker = walker->next;
  }

  return walker;
}

template <typename T>
void swap(List<T>& lhs, List<T>& rhs) {
  using std::swap;

  swap(lhs.m_head, rhs.m_head);
  swap(lhs.m_tail, rhs.m_tail);
  swap(lhs.m_size, rhs.m_size);
}

/*
 * List Iterator Implementation
 */
template <typename T>
List<T>::iterator::iterator(Node* node) : m_pos(node) {}

template <typename T>
T& List<T>::iterator::operator*() {
  return m_pos->data;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator& List<T>::iterator::operator++() {
  m_pos = m_pos->next;

  return *this;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::iterator::operator++(int) {
  iterator tmp(m_pos);
  ++(*this);

  return tmp;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator& List<T>::iterator::operator--() {
  m_pos = m_pos->prev;

  return *this;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::iterator::operator--(int) {
  iterator tmp(m_pos);
  --(*this);

  return tmp;
}

template <typename T>
bool List<T>::iterator::operator==(const iterator& other) {
  return m_pos == other.m_pos;
}

template <typename T>
bool List<T>::iterator::operator!=(const iterator& other) {
  return !(*this == other);
}

#endif
```

Yep. And it's not complete. To be a bit fair, it's not that far off either.

And here's the modified `main()` function:

```cpp
#include "niceList.hpp"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> list_size(100, 200);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> element_range(0, 50);

  int num;
  std::cout << "Number: ";
  std::cin >> num;

  std::map<int, int> intCountPerList;
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    int size = list_size(prng);
    List<int> list;

    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
      list.push_back(element_range(prng));
    }

    int occurences[51]{0};
    for (auto num : list) {
      ++occurences[num];
    }

    for (int idx = 0; idx < 51; ++idx) {
      if (occurences[idx] > 0) {
        ++intCountPerList[idx];
      }
    }

  }

  std::cout << "Numbers that appeared in at least half of the 'lists': \n";
  int numLength = std::to_string(num).length();
  for (auto count : intCountPerList) {
    if (count.second >= num / 2) {
      std::cout << std::setw(numLength) << count.first << ": " << count.second
                << " times.\n";
    }
  }
}
```

If you just compare the `main()` functions side by side, you can see the pointless extra work that this one does. I was tempted, again, to skip the list and go straight to the counting array. A linked list is absolutely a waste of time and energy for this task. We're talking a 40 line program versus something at least 2-3 as large if you're required to write the list yourself. And it's far less efficient to boot.